# Why is there a page in a CiviCRM WordPress install that says "Do not delete this page."

Tags: wordpress, base-page

A CiviCRM page is created on the site:
my-site-wordpress/CiviCRM
where it says: "Do not delete this page." Page content is generated by CiviCRM "
what is it for? how should it work?
What should appear on this page?
I use WordPress 4.9.6 version - CiviCRM is in a subdirectory
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CiviCRM has some public-facing pages that it generates. e.g. event registrations, unsubscribe confirmations etc.

On Wordpress the page you're seeing is the one that's used by CiviCRM for these purposes. So it's not a page you use or link to directly yourself, but it has to exist as far as Wordpress is concerned so that CiviCRM can provide dynamic content.

### EDIT

Here's an example of when CiviCRM will use this page. You have an event, you want to give people a link to sign up for it.

From the Manage Events page you click (1) event links, then you see (2) test and live event registration links. You right-click the one you want and choose "Copy Link Location" (or whatever similar description your browser offers), and send people the link.

When people click that link CiviCRM will use the base page to decorate its sign up form.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: ok, how do you generate dynamic content? what should I set up? thank you

Comment: Hi @simonettaofficinecollegate, I'm not clear what you want to achieve. Basically you don't need to worry about that page - just ignore it (and obviously make sure it's not linked to in your menus or anything like that!)

Comment: I thought it was essential on the front end, so I can exclude it from the menu?
But if I wanted to use it, how could I do? thank you

Comment: For example: if I want a person to sign up for an event?

Comment: thanks artfulrobot, I had already seen this possibility, but it was not clear to me. Now I see that I can activate the registration for an event, but where can I show this event and the possibility to register? ...
Can I do this, inserting the link that I find at the bottom on created event? This is not automatic? Thank you

Comment: Where you can show the event is a question for your website. CiviCRM provides a link, where you put that link is up to you. You may find the [events documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/integrating-events-with-your-website/) useful.

Comment: @simonettaofficinecollegate no worries, welcome to the community! Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick button on the left. Otherwise other community members may think it still needs answers.

Comment: Sorry artfulrobot, you say: "Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check button on the left"  but I don't see where to click ... thanks

Comment: To the left of where my answer starts, you should see a few buttons. There's the ↑ up arrow, the ↓ down arrow and under that a ✔ check/tick button. It's the ✔ button that you, as the person who asked the question, can tick to 'accept' the answer. There's a brief intro to how this site works at [tour](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour)