# Hiding the WordPress 'do not delete this page' page

Tags: wordpress, base-page

We've been using Drupal 7 for years, but need to move off before EoL, so I'm testing WordPress as an alternative. I found an explanation of the 'do not delete this page' page in [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25463/why-is-there-a-page-in-a-civicrm-wordpress-install-that-says-do-not-delete-this), but no mention of how to exclude it from menus. All I can find in WordPress an option to make it private, but presumably that will prevent it from being seen by users when it's needed? Do I need a third-party plugin to exclude it from the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a menu that doesn't have "Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu" checked. Or, yes, use a plugin. [This simple one](https://gist.github.com/christianwach/931bdf52803a35e363043ad0302fd4be) or something like it should do the job. Pop it in your "must use" plugins folder at `wp-content/mu-plugins` - create that directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you!  Any chance of adding that to your Admin Utilities plugin?

Comment: @Aidan Not sure about that... CAU is really for things that are common to all sites. Site menus often need handling individually - they can have lots of menus, some of which may want to have the link, some not. The point of this plugin is that it can be modified on a per site basis.

Comment: Ok, I was wondering whether it could just be an option in CAU but I take your point about customising per site.  For this CiviCRM page, is there any reason one would want to include it in a menu? So far as I understand (which is limited!!), it is only ever used as the base for displaying Civi content.

Comment: @Aidan Short answer: who am I to say what people do? :-) Longeranswer: I guess it could be an option for those who want to enable it in CAU, but I can't think of a site I've worked on that uses a menu with "Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu" checked.